# "Pervert" Vs "Deviate" as verbs

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

I wonder how the following pairs differ in meaning?

1. The history teacher tried to ([pervert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prevent) / [deviate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deviate)) the boys by showing
   them pornographic magazines.
2. These journalists by reporting false information are ([perverting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prevent) / [deviating](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deviate)) the news.

To me, both sentences in each pair mean the same and cannot figure out their differences by dictionary definitions.

Comment: Look closely at the examples in the dictionary definitions. One word is typically followed by an object; the other is not.

Comment: The obvious difference is that as a verb, ***pervert*** is *transitive*, whereas ***deviate*** is *intransitive*. So both of OP's examples are invalid with ***deviate***, because they both feature an *object* after the verb *(**the boys, the news**)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "pervert" is to corrupt, to take something good and make it evil.

To "deviate" is to vary from the plan or to head in the wrong direction.

In the two examples you give, "pervert" makes sense. "Deviate" does not.

An example of "deviate" with a literal meaning is, "We originally planned to go straight to Chicago but then we deviated from that course and took a side trip to Detroit." It can be used in a metaphorical sense of deviating from a plan or from good conduct. Like, "President Jones made a good plan but then his staff deviated from the plan so much that it accomplished little good."

"Deviate" doesn't work in your examples because there is no reference to a plan or goal that someone is deviating from. You could, of course, reword the sentences to express the same idea but introducing the idea of a plan. Like, "The boys were on the road to moral excellence but then the teacher tried to get them to deviate from that path by showing them pornography." But it takes some pretty heavy rewording.

If you deviate, you are always deviating from something, and the context should make clear what you are deviating from. Not necessarily in the same sentence, but in context. Like you could say, "Have a plan. Stick to the plan. Don't deviate." But really, I haven't checked statistics, but I think most sentences that use the word "deviate" follow it with "from" and what you are deviating from.

Comment: Well, just out of curiosity; how about "Some parents believe that the violence on TV programs can (**pervert / deviate**) the minds of children." @Jay? If I'm not mistaken, "deviate" does not work here as well. Am I right?

Comment: @A-friend No, deviate the mind's of children no. Generally speaking, the verb deviate is used like this: This assumption deviates from the rule that [blah blah blah]. To deviate and deviation are not associated with "a deviant" except for the idea of a semantic trait that suggests being outside some boundary.

Comment: I agree that *deviate* definitely does not work - but does *pervert* really work for you in these sentences?  *He perverted the boys* sounds very strange to me - especially if the intended meaning is *made them into perverts*.  Boys' minds could be perverted, but not the boys themselves.

Comment: @Juhasz I'm not sure I'd say it, but it sounds fine, if a tad unusual.

Comment: @A-friend Correct, "deviate" doesn't work there either. You could recast it to something like, "... violence on TV can cause the minds of children to deviate from the proper path." But you have to have some goal or plan, and then say that you are deviating from that goal or plan.